# How to fix login process to dialogflow after I have attached gmail to my non-gmail account?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gmail, dialogflow-es, google-signin

I had a Google account based on not-GMail-account. I had another email company's email as a login to my Google Account (myemailhere@ukr.net). And I used this Google account to login the dialogflow.cloud.google.com.

Today Google suggested me to create a @gmail.com account and attcach it to my myemailhere@ukr.net Google Account. I have confirmed and created the myemailhere@gmail.com.

Using both of this logins (myemailhere@gmail.com and myemailhere@ukr.net) I am still able to login my cloud.google.com Profile. But when I try to login the Dialogflow Profile (dialogflow.cloud.google.com) - I see the eternal loading animation (or a totally blank page). There is no errors about password or something like this. Just login process after I submit the password and then white page. This behavior I see on all my devices, while I trying to login with myemailhere@gmail.com or myemailhere@ukr.net

And I see some 400 errors in web console (if it matters).

Could you please help me to fix this and get access to DialogFlow?

[Screen that I see after the login and password entering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmw9P.png)

Comment: Thank tou in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the project owner role for the mentioned username that is registered on your project in the GCP console (not Dalogflow Console)? Here is a [list](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/access-control#roles) of roles related to Dialogflow that grant access to its Console.

Note that some of these roles give full access or edit access while other roles have permissions that simply gives view access to the Dialogflow Console.

If you are missing any of these then simply [assign](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-console) on your GCP project's console.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning roles as described above did not work for me. Solution was to delete gmail email service from the account.

Instructions  [here](https://myaccount.google.com/intro/delete-services-or-account)

If you would like to use gmail, do NOT add gmail to your existing google account. You should instead create a seperate google account and use gmail from this seperate account